# File present in "recent files" of nautilus, but I was not who opened it!

Tags: nautilus, security, privacy

Consider now it is 12:05 pm. I had finished working on a file (say 12:02 pm), I saved it and I wanted to attach it to an email, so I browsed for it, selected "recent files", and oops! The last file in "recent files" was not the file I had just saved. There was another file of mine, which Nautilus said it was accessed (say) 12:04! Who and how opened/accessed that file? I did not, and I was working on my same laptop on that very time.

Comment: Your recent file list is held in your `~.local/share/recently-used.xbel`. Access times on file systems with SSDs is a complicated matter. Was you truly last visited file in the list?

Comment: @xenoid such a useful file, thank you. No, it was not me accessing the file. But, since the file is a Word document, and it has been opened with LibreOffice writer the same version I use on my laptop, it is likely not a security issue, but how and why it is listed there and opened with writer? I do not know